# Calculate business/working days C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to know the working days when I choose the date in this grid. I tried JavaScript code that works but I have some difficulty using it in C#.

[image]

```
     string startdate, enddate;
        startdate = "";
        enddate = "";

        foreach (GridViewRow row in DateGrid.Rows) 
        {

            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("DateChBox") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    startdate = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    enddate = row.Cells[3].Text;

     // Validate input
    if (enddate < startdate)
    return 0;

// Calculate days between dates
var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
startdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);  // Start just after midnight  --> how to do this in c#?
enddate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);  // End just before midnight --> how to do this in c#?
var diff = enddate - startdate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
var days = Math.Ceiling(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

// Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
var weeks = Math.Floor(days / 7);
days = days - (weeks * 2);

//// Handle special cases  --> this is not necessary because I choose the date
//var startDay = startdate.getDay(); 
//var endDay = enddate.getDay();

// Remove weekend not previously removed.   
if (startDay - endDay > 1)         
    days = days - 2;      

// Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
    days = days - 1;  
}

// Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
    days = days - 1;
}
```

I need some help to use it in C# if it is possible.

Comment: try `System.Datetime.Parse` it will return you date with midnight time and use it as startdate and than parse enddate with same function and add 23 Hours,59 Min. and 59 sec. to enddate

Comment: please read about `System.Datetime` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert your dates in dateformat, and loop from `startdate` to `endday`.

Then you can do this:

```
if (!(toValidate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || toValidate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
{
    // do your logic 
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
int countWorkingDays = 0;
string startdate1 = "2014/04/28";
string enddate1 = "2014/09/12";

DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate1, "yyyy/MM/dd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(enddate1, "yyyy/MM/dd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date = startdate;

while (date <= enddate)
{
    if (!(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
    {
        countWorkingDays++;
    }
    date = date.AddDays(1);  
}

Console.WriteLine("WorkingDays " + countWorkingDays);
```

Comment: @Nakala have some code with that you wrote but it gives me wrong days.. eg in the second row date, returns something like 342 working days

Comment: @MaraPimentel : Update

Comment: I did it :) I will update my question to help someone with the same problem..  But when I make a reponse.write too see how many days   a date has it gives me 1,2,3,4...99 (the chosen date has 100 working days) How can I return only 100 working days to show on a label or something?

Comment: @MaraPimentel ok well.Also my example display 100 days as you expected.is it ok please set as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DateTime date = Start_Date; date <= End_Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            yield return date;
        }
    }
```

removes weekends from date range.